# How do I tell an Observable that my array is complete

Tags: javascript, arrays, rxjs, observable

TLDR: How can I tell an Observed array to complete. See [this jsBin](https://jsbin.com/viqolitipa/2/edit?js,console) for example.

I am new to Observables so I may be coming at this from the wrong angle. Given the code below, [or this jsBin](https://jsbin.com/viqolitipa/2/edit?js,console), what should I be doing differently to get the User's sites array to "complete".

```js
let firstUser = {
  name: 'Susan',
  sites: [
    {company: 'ABC Co', role: 'admin'},
    {company: 'XYZ Co', role: 'reader'}
  ]
};

user = new Rx.BehaviorSubject(firstUser);

function authorized(authRoles) {
    // check if the current user has one of the authorizedRoles roles
    return this.user
      .do(user => console.log("Checking user: ",JSON.stringify(user)))
      .flatMap( user => user.sites )
      .do(res => console.log("Mapped user roles: ",res))
      .first( site => authRoles.indexOf(site.role) !== -1 ) // only return when a role matches
      .do( res => console.log('First: ',res))
      .map( res => true)
}

// This one finds a match and completes
authorized(['writer','admin','reader']).subscribe(res =>{
  console.log("1: isAuthorized?: ",res);
}, err => {
  console.log("1: ERROR: User is not authorized!");
}, () => {
  console.log("1: Authorized check completed!");
});

// This one never completes
authorized(['writer','foo']).subscribe(res =>{
  console.log("2: isAuthorized?: ",res);
}, err => {
  console.log("2: ERROR: User is not authorized!");
}, () => {
  console.log("2: Authorized check completed!");
});
```

Note that (first)[http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-first] should throw an error if it doesn't find one, but only if the Observable completes.

The above will return properly and complete if a match is found, but it will never complete or error without a match because the array of user.sites never completes.

Is there a way to make the array complete? I can get it to work if I fetch/subscribe to the user first:

```js
//
// Pretend that fetchedUser is fetched in a safer/more sane way

// fetch the user and set it
let fetchedUser;
user.subscribe(user => fetchedUser = user);

function authorized2(authRoles) {
    // check if the current user has one of the authorizedRoles roles
    return Rx.Observable.of(this.fetchedUser.sites)
      .do(sites => console.log("auth2: Checking users sites: ",sites))
      .flatMap( sites => sites )
      .do(res => console.log("Mapped user roles: ",res))
      .first( site => authRoles.indexOf(site.role) !== -1 ) // only return when a role matches
      .do( res => console.log('First: ',res))
      .map( res => true)
}
```

I feel like I am missing a crucial but yet simple step to get this to work using pure Observables. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/behaviorsubject.md#usage

Comment: @Dom I'm not sure what you are getting at. The second example shows using something like that, but I don't feel that is the correct way or can find any articles, etc that say otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Rx.Observable.of(this.fetchedUser.sites)` converts its arguments to an observable sequence and then completes. This triggers the `.first` operator to throw an exception. You are never completing the `this.user` subject. You could change it to `this.user.take(1)` or even `Rx.Observable.of(fetchedUser)` and skip making it a behavior subject if you want it to complete. Or you could change your `.first` to a `.map` so that it returns false if the user is unauthorized. Here is an example of using the `take` operator.

```js
const user = Rx.Observable.create((o) => {
  window.setTimeout(() => {
    o.next({
      name: 'Susan',
      sites: [
        {company: 'ABC Co', role: 'admin'},
        {company: 'XYZ Co', role: 'reader'}
      ]
    });
  }, 1000);
});

function authorized(authRoles) {
    return user
      .take(1)
      .flatMap( user => user.sites )
      .first( site => authRoles.indexOf(site.role) !== -1 )
      .map( res => true);
}

authorized(['writer','admin','reader']).subscribe(res =>{
  console.log("1: isAuthorized?: ",res);
}, err => {
  console.log("1: ERROR: User is not authorized!");
}, () => {
  console.log("1: Authorized check completed!");
});

authorized(['writer','foo']).subscribe(res =>{
  console.log("2: isAuthorized?: ",res);
}, err => {
  console.log("2: ERROR: User is not authorized!");
}, () => {
  console.log("2: Authorized check completed!");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.2/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

After looking at your example I am left wondering why you are trying to solve this problem with RxJs. RxJs is tailored for acting on streams of data but you are acting on a static value. Maybe your example is just simplifying what actually occurs in your app but you could just accomplish what you are going for without RxJs in a synchronous manner and it would be much simpler. Here is an example:

```
function authorized(authRoles) {
    return firstUser.sites.some(x => authRoles.includes(x));
}
```

Comment: I covered using Rx.Observable.of in the JSBin, but I think what I really want to know is, can I know or somehow tell it to "complete" an Observable array as given? I do know that the example I gave is not really how they should be used, but it does represent similar logic to what I would need for an actual use case. As written, the last part of your answer is spot on.

Comment: @jrose The `.take(1)` will complete the stream after one item flows through it. On what condition do you want to complete?

Comment: I want it to complete after all "sites" have flowed through.

Comment: @jrose There is only one item that flows through the stream until the flatMap. So if you use the `of` operator on a static value or the `take` on an observable before the flatmap then the completion comes after all sites have flowed through.

Comment: @jrose I added an example of using `take`.

Comment: Correct, but I cannot `take` if I don't know how many objects there should be. I looked at `takeUntil` but I don't really have a stopping point since I am looking for the absence of something. I think my current example is limited. I'll see if I can make a better one. As written though, I think your answer is exactly what it needs. Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you are going to have multiple users emitted then you probably shouldn't use `flatMap`. Just do `map` with `sites.some(x => authRoles.includes(x))` to return true/false or even throw an error from it on false. No need to emit the sites separately via a flatMap.